# How do I get innerHTML of document before parsing?

Tags: javascript

I'm thinking of developing an HTML linter, that runs client-side. This linter would need access to the HTML of the document as served exactly by the server.

Here's an example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<p>One
<p>Two
<script>
console.log(document.documentElement.innerHTML); // this prints the parsed HTML, not the HTML as is
</script>
```

This prints to the console:

```html
<head></head><body><p>One
</p><p>Two
<script>
console.log(document.documentElement.innerHTML); // this prints the parsed HTML, not the HTML as is
</script></p></body>
```

As you can see, this is not the output I wanted. I wanted to have the output be exactly the same as the HTTP response, byte for byte, including the doctype declaration, and without the added tags like `<head></head>`. Is this possible? Is this possible in a browser extension?

Comment: I don't think this is possible as HTML is fault tolerant . The browser auto-closes tags and adds missing ones.

Comment: have you considered simply calling that page with an xhr request and print the result into your console?

Comment: You wouldn't be able to do it on the currently loaded page as that code has already been parsed. You would need to request the file, either by file input or ajax request to get the file. Note though if this is completely client side (you are running from a `file:///` url) you won't be able to do an ajax request

Answer (score 2):

I think the only way would be to re-fetch the document. If you want to fetch the HTML of the current page you could do something like this:

```js
fetch('.')
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then(html => console.log(html));
```

This way it will be untouched HTML sent from the server.

If you want, you can also process it later on, with something like [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily enough by re-fetching the page's content, if you don't mind asynchronicity and an additional HTTP request:

```js
;(async () => {
    const res = await fetch('.')

    const text = await res.text()

    console.log(text)
})()
```

Comment: Nope, no such thing as `res.HTML()` (and if there was, you wouldn't want to use it, because in this case OP specifically wants the un-parsed version).

Comment: Oh yes, I was thinking of [`res.json()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response#:~:text=Body.json())